# To adjust the view when keyboard is on the android

Tags: android

I have a activity in which there are 15 editText box. My problem is that when the soft keyboard comes up the editText present at bottom hides. I tried

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

in Manifest file. But this did not worked.

I want edit Text boxes present at bottom to come up when they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout make the ScrollView to be the root parent, and they will go up by default.

To force the ScrollView to scroll to bottom (if it doesn't by default), you can implement the following:

```
scrollView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        scrollView().fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a Scroll view in which there is Relative Layout which contains my editText boxes.